# Spring MVC 4.1 RedirectAttributes is not working properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to the Spring MVC. I am using the Spring release 4.1.6 and deployed my two web applications A and B on tomcat 7 for the development environment. But in the actual production environment the application A will be deployed on weblogic and application B will be deployed on websphere. Below is the scenario occuring on the development environment.

Application A has testrequest.jsp page available in the test directory.Below is the code for the jsp page.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test Media Request</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Fill your form123!</h2>
<form:form method="post" commandName="testobj" action="http://localhost:8080/b/createtestrequest.test">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter your name:</td>
            <td><form:input  path="requestId" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="requestId" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

If we look at the action attribute of the form carefully , when the form submits the request must go to the TestController.java. TestController.java has methods to handler the **GET**(load the page) and **POST**(submit the page) request.Below is the code for the same.

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
@RequestMapping(value="/createtestrequest.test",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String  requestForm(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs){
        System.out.println("*********** Get Request reaches the TestController *******************");

        RequestDetails obj=new RequestDetails();
        obj.setRequestId("12345");
        redirectAttrs.addAttribute("testobj", obj);

        return "redirect:http://localhost:8080/a/test/testrequest.jsp";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/createtestrequest.test",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void submitForm(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs){
                    System.out.println("*********** Post Request reaches the TestController *******************");


    }

}
```

Below is the RequestDetails(Model) object available in the  application B.

```
public class RequestDetails implements java.io.Serializable{

    String requestId;        

    public String getRequestId() {
        return requestId;
    }
    public void setRequestId(String requestId) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
    }
}
```

When I am executing the URL to display the jsp page **http://localhost:8080/b/createtestrequest.test** (to set the empty model object in the request)  then the controller method**(requestForm(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs)**) to handle get request does gets invoked with the below output but it does redirect to the page testrequest.jsp available in the test directory of the Application A. But it is giving the below error on the browser

**output on the tomcat console**

*********** Get Request reaches the TestController *******************

Below is the error coming on the browser

```
org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'com.test.bean.RequestDetails' to required type 'java.lang.String'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.test.bean.RequestDetails] to required type [java.lang.String]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:74)
    org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:40)
    org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:596)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributesModelMap.formatValue(RedirectAttributesModelMap.java:79)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributesModelMap.addAttribute(RedirectAttributesModelMap.java:71)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributesModelMap.addAttribute(RedirectAttributesModelMap.java:34)
    com.cira.raws.mediawf.api.services.controller.MediaWFController.requestForm(MediaWFController.java:87)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.test.bean.RequestDetails] to required type [java.lang.String]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:287)
    org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:107)
    org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:64)
    org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:40)
    org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:596)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributesModelMap.formatValue(RedirectAttributesModelMap.java:79)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributesModelMap.addAttribute(RedirectAttributesModelMap.java:71)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributesModelMap.addAttribute(RedirectAttributesModelMap.java:34)
    com.cira.raws.mediawf.api.services.controller.MediaWFController.requestForm(MediaWFController.java:87)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

I somehow need the Userdefined object "testobj"available in my request object to load the test.jsp page with the available values in the object but it seems to be not working as expected.I have two questions

1. Is it possible to make the user defined object available using the RedirectAttribute class in the case of redirecting the request using some other workaround?
2. In future I will be validating the jsp form using the Spring Validation support in that case I need to made available org.springframework.validation.BindingResult object to my jsp page in the application A so will that be possible as well?

Comment: I am not completely clear from your description on what you are trying to do but I noticed that you are updating RedirectAttributes but you are not returning them.

Try `return new ModelAndView( "redirect:http://localhost:8080/a/test/testrequest.jsp", redirectAttributes);`

Comment: @jny thanks for the prompt reply. I will tryout the solution. but please let me know which part of the question is not making sense, so I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: In simpler terms let me explain the problem.  I have jsp page in application A , when I  execute the url to load the page, the controller is available on application B needs to be invoked.The controller must set the model object and redirect to the jsp page on the application A.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand your question better. Please disregard my suggestion and see the answer.

Comment: That is never going to work an object instance in application a is never going to be available in application b. Even if you would use flash attributes this wouldn't work, the objects remain on the same server...

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your answer. Just a follow up question is this a good design having the JSP page on one server and the controller which is also the part of the presentation layer and required to handle the POST and GET request of the page on the different server ?

Comment: That will only make sense if they aren't coupled. If you use the objects directly in the JSP that will not work, it would/could work with, for instance, a JSON or XML interface.

Answer (score 5):

To add a user defined object, i believe you need to use addFlashAttribute.

[Example](http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-redirectview-example-add-fetch-flash-attributes-redirectattributes-model-requestcontextutils)